# Django cms remove href attribute from Textplugin

Tags: python, django, django-cms, html-sanitizing, djangocms-text-ckeditor

Currently I am working with Django-CMS & trying to add below code in Text Plugin.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="map-world">Click me!</a>
```

But Django-CMS automatically removes the href attribute from text plugin and after save Text plugin has below content.

```
<a id="map-world">Click me!</a>
```

As a solution I have already tried below options which I have got from online search.

```
TEXT_ADDITIONAL_TAGS = ('iframe', 'div', 'a')
TEXT_ADDITIONAL_ATTRIBUTES = ('href', 'onclick')
TEXT_HTML_SANITIZE = False
```

but still not any solution working.

Please let me know if anyone have solution.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you save the following?

`<a href="/non/script/url" id="map-world">Click me!</a>`

Comment: @Aiky30 yes above code working properly but I need anchor tag with `javascript:void(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design to prevent Cross Site Scripting attacks (XSS). If you are binding javascript to the element you can just use the # character and return false in the on click function.

Click me!